# When is a Banach Algebra stellar?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-algebras, c-star-algebras

I know that if there are enough Hermitian elements in a Banach algebra, then the Banach algebra is stellar. In particular, I'm interested in the two spaces $B(L^1(S^1,\Sigma,\mu))$ the space of bounded linear operators on Lebesgue integrable functions of the circle and $B(ba(\Sigma))$ the space of bounded linear operators on finite, finitely-additive Borel measures. I know about the results that having enough Hermitian elements is sufficient, but I'm not quite sure how to apply them.

The issue comes up because I am trying to bound the inverse of a Hermitian element in terms of its spectral radius. From my reading, we have an equality for $C^\star$ algebras and an inequality for Banach algebras.

Comment: What is a stellar Banach algebra?

Comment: @Rasmus I think inolutive banach algebra with identity $\Vert a\Vert=\Vert a^*\Vert$

Comment: Cross-posted at MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/103229/when-is-a-banach-algebra-c-star

Comment: That's exactly what I meant, Norbert. Thanks.

Comment: Daniel and @Norbert: the first sentence appears to allude to the Vidav-Palmer theorem, but the conclusion of that theorem is stronger than being involutive with isometric involution: the conclusion is that we actually get a $C^*$-algebra. So I am not sure whether this mention of stellar Banach algebras is precisely what is meant.

Comment: @YemonChoi this is a very good reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The question was cross-posted at mathoverflow and answered [there](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103229/when-is-a-banach-algebra-c-star).

Credits goes to Yemon Choi.

Comment: No problem. I upvoted.